# I sent some xtz from an exchange to my KT1 account. Tzstats shows a transaction error "proto.005-PsBabyM1.gas_exhausted.operation"

Tags: transactions

I sent some xtz from an exchange to my Kt1 account, and I believe I did not received the balance. When I look at the transaction on Tzstats, that particular transaction is shown in red and there is no value on the amount received column (just says '-'). When I click the transaction hash, it says transaction error "proto.005-PsBabyM1.gas_exhausted.operation". It also says 'transaction failed'.

The weird part is when I look at the transaction on tezblock, it says the transaction was received, but I don't think my balance has been updated. So, I am kind of confused with what's happening. Can anybody help me please? How do i solve this issue regarding receiving my xtz to my kt1 account?

Comment: The tx failed. Which exchange was that ? Please contact them asap as it means many other tx might be failing too

Answer (score 1):

If it says ''transaction failed'' on multiple block explorers, you need to contact the exchange, as something is wrong on their end. Make sure to provide your tx/id or some kind of reference so they can assist you more rapidly!

Edit: The gas cost for sending from a tz address to a KT address (manager.tz) went from ~10 300 to 15 400 after Babylon. Based on you info It seems that the exchange hasn't updated properly to Babylon.